# H1 containing html tags

Tags: html, css, seo

So I'm creating a new website and in the design I got, the H1 is made up really design-specifically.. it has word breaks, words are aligned a certain way, some words can have a different color, it has some icons etc.. So every H1 looks pretty different (you get the idea). I created the titles using css grid to layout everything nicely.

- It's not semantically correct if my H1 contains HTML tags, it will cause invalid markup.
  (apparently SPAN tags are allowed)
- It's also not good to add an H1 on the page and hide it on the page

Does anyone know what the correct way to go about this is?
With "correct" I mean "semantically correct" as well as correct for SEO.

I guess I could make the H1s up in SPANS, as that's the most correct?

Would love to hear some opinions.

What do you think?

Comment: Correct way to go about... **what**?  It isn't clear at all what you're doing.  The markup is to be used for setting the context of the content.  The CSS is to be used for styling it.  If every `<h1>` looks different, are they actually all the same type of content... a primary heading?  Only you know this... you didn't tell/show us...

Comment: If your question is, *What is the effect on SEO of H1 containing html tags*, then that should be asked at [webmasters.se].  General SEO questions are off-topic on stack overflow as explained in [the tag's help page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info), but are [explicitly on-topic at webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).